# Flash CS6, Stop at this frame not working for me

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs6

As the title suggests I'm having problems. I have been working on a project for weeks for my UNI course. Today Flash CS6 crashed and after painstakingly recovering my work all the code was a mess. The thing is, I deleted all the code from the first frame and and now with only stop at this frame on the first frame it still cycles through all my project. Anyone try and explain why this isnt working please? It cycles through the frames after testing obviously.

[image: screenshot]

Stop at this frame, which is frame number one. I don't know what else you need to know?
I have the stop action as you see in the image but it juts scrolls through the movie without pausing at frame one.

Comment: You'll have to post some more code, as I can't really understand what you mean by "Stop at this frame not working for me"

Comment: i dont know what else you need more then what i have described? The first frame has stop in the code as seen in the pic/link i provided. It doesnt stop though, just goes to the next frames.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like to me that you have a bug. When you have any type of bug it will cycle through the entire movie. Check to see if there is any errors in the error console.

Comment: console is error free but i have a error 1065 variable not defined but that appears later after testing as if it's further into the project on a later frame. Could that be a conflict?

Comment: If it's a bug can my project be saved?

Comment: sorry new to stack overflow. Can you post your file somewhere? Then I can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it only in Flash or also with a release swf / in a browser ?
Depending on the size of what you already made, you could also consider making a new flash project and copy/pasting everything to see if it resolves the problem.